# Tooltips in LWC for template iterator are hidden by z-index

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, css, component, web

[image]

I have a tooltip slds div which is displayed when hovered over Task bar (task three in this case) 
Its just that the even after setting z index (100000) on the popover component (from slds), it hides under the component either above or below it.(Task Three, Four, Five are in a component, theres another div below them housing other task bars)

[Similar stackexchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174911/tooltips-not-displaying-in-modal-content)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use [Scrollable](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/scrollable/) which implements [scrollbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars), this is bound to happen.

#### Problem

The part of the DOM which is inside scroll is limited to its own context. The standard helptext will add DOM element which is **fixed** (position `fixed`) w.r.t the `i` or any other element you choose - in effect its just another DOM element.

#### Solution

The only solution I found so far to this is using `title` attribute. This adds the popup over the top of DOM by browser. Also if you need to style the title, you can do so by CSS.

Comment: Thanks @salesforce-sas, there seems no way to modify css on the default title attribute though, even with the help of css psuedo elements

Comment: I did it before - long time back, its definitely possible, just post a question. Meanwhile I will check if I can do it, or else somebody else would atleast answer for lwc/salesforce context

Comment: I'm using this 
https://css-tricks.com/css-content/#example-trick-css3-tooltips